# Counter is starting at 2, instead of at 1

Tags: javascript, css, html

In the following snippet, pressing the "-" button makes the number on the left side of the equals sign count down until it reaches 0, whereby it and the plus sign disappear. If I then press the "+" button, the plus sign and the left number return, but the number starts at 2 instead of 1. Why is the number not starting at 1? It's not double counting, because each subsequent press of the "+" button increases the number by 1, not 2.

```js
function leftMinusButton() {
  var valvariable = (parseInt(document.getElementById("variable").style.top, 10) || 120) - 5;
  document.getElementById("variable").style.top = valvariable +  "px";
  
  var valplus = (parseInt(document.getElementById("plus").style.top, 10) || 120) - 5;
  document.getElementById("plus").style.top = valplus +  "px";
  
  var valleftnum = (parseInt(document.getElementById("leftnum").style.top, 10) || 120) - 5;
  document.getElementById("leftnum").style.top = valleftnum +  "px";

  var valrightnum = (parseInt(document.getElementById("rightnum").style.top, 10) || 120) + 5;
  document.getElementById("rightnum").style.top = valrightnum +  "px";
}

function leftPlusButton() {
  var valvariable = (parseInt(document.getElementById("variable").style.top, 10) || 30) + 5;
  document.getElementById("variable").style.top = valvariable +  "px";
  
  var valplus = (parseInt(document.getElementById("plus").style.top, 10) || 30) + 5;
  document.getElementById("plus").style.top = valplus +  "px";
  
  var valleftnum = (parseInt(document.getElementById("leftnum").style.top, 10) || 30) + 5;
  document.getElementById("leftnum").style.top = valleftnum +  "px";
  
  var valrightnum = (parseInt(document.getElementById("rightnum").style.top, 10) || 30) - 5;
  document.getElementById("rightnum").style.top = valrightnum +  "px";
  }

  
function leftCountDown() {  
  var i = document.getElementById("leftnum");
  var value = parseInt(i.innerHTML);
  if (value > 0) {
    value--;
  }  
  i.innerHTML = value;

  if (value <= 0) {  
  document.getElementById("plus").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("leftnum").style.display="none";
  }
}

function leftCountUp() {
  var i = document.getElementById("leftnum");
  var value = parseInt(i.innerHTML);
  if (value <= 0) {
    value++;
  }

  if (value > 0) {
    document.getElementById("plus").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("leftnum").style.display="block";
    value++;
  }

  i.innerHTML = value;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial,"times new roman";
  background: lightblue;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  }
    
.leftminus {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 40px;
  }

.leftplus {
  position: absolute;
  top: 170px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 40px;
  }
    
.variable {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 115px;
  font-size: 40px;
  }
    
.plus {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 175px;
  font-size: 40px;
  }
    
.leftnum {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 240px;
  font-size: 40px;
  }
    
.equals {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 300px;
  font-size: 40px;
  }
   
.rightnum {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 350px;
  font-size: 40px;
  }
```

```html
  <div id="workspace">
      <div class="variable" id="variable">x</div>
      <div class="plus" id="plus">+</div>
      <div class="leftnum" id="leftnum">7</div>
      <div class="equals" id="equals">=</div>
      <div class="rightnum" id="rightnum">19</div>
  </div>

  <div id="plusminus">
    <button type="button" class="leftminus" id="leftminus" onclick="leftMinusButton(); leftCountDown();">-</button>
    <button type="button" class="leftplus" id="leftplus" onclick="leftPlusButton(); leftCountUp()">+</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function leftCountUp() {
  var i = document.getElementById("leftnum");
  var value = parseInt(i.innerHTML);
  if (value <= 0) {
    value++;
  }

  if (value > 0) {
    document.getElementById("plus").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("leftnum").style.display="block";
    value++;
  }

  i.innerHTML = value;
}
```

You are increasing value twice - at the beginning value is zero - increase it once. Then value is 1, so it enters second if.
Change that `if (value > 0)` to `else` and it should be fine

Edit: Or change it as epascarello suggested. Depending on what are you trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is doing it

```
if (value <= 0) {
  value++;  // <-- Adds one to zero to make one
}

if (value > 0) {
  ...
  value++;  // <-- Adds one to one to make  two
}
```

First if should probably just be

```
if (value < 0) {
  value = 0
}
```

Comment: For some reason, this didn't work. It's probably conflicting with some of the code that I didn't publish.